# Gaussian filter with cut-off frequency

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gaussian

I am asked to apply Gaussian filter to an image with a specific cut-off frequency. 
I understand that sigma or the size of the Gaussian filter surely does influence the filtering of intensities and have correspondence with cut-off frequency, but what if I was asked to send cut-off frequency as a parameter to a function.
Suppose the function to get Gaussian filtered image is like this: "Filter-With-Gaussian(Image, Cut-off-frequency)".

Comment: The [Wikipedia page for Gaussian filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter) gives you the relationship between sigma and cut-off frequency. You probably want the -3 dB point (c = 2).

Comment: For the programming part if this question, check [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/fspecial.html)